# DOM Manipulation - Add 3 new divs (possibly using Node.cloneNode?) after pressing a button

Tags: javascript, html

**Context**: I'm trying to create a button so that every time someone presses it, it adds 3 new divs (one for the `Ativo` (ativo =  stock in English), one for `Quota%`, and another for `Perda Potencial`). I'm starting by simply adding the `Ativo` `div` first to try this out. Then, I created a `valuePercentage` variable that would take the amount of `slices` on the pie chart (amount of slices = amount of `ativos` divs) so that I can get the `Quota%` (the quota is essentially 100 divided by the number of `Ativos`. Initially, I have 5 fixed so each `Ativo` will be 20%. This % should be adjusted as the user presses the "Add stock" button. If the user adds 5 more ativos, this Quota% should be 10, etc).

**Problem**: The method to add divs that I'm using isn't working and I was looking at using node.cloneNode, but I'd like to generate new `ativo` IDs and not clone them. Could we mix node.cloneNode with template literals and a for loop so that the 3 divs are cloned, but the index of each `ativo` is changed (from 1 to 15 for example?). I currently have ativo1, ativo2, ativo3, ativo4 and ativo 5, and when the user presses the button, it should add new divs with ids like ativo 6, ativo7, etc

```js
    //https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y17RuWkWdn8&ab_channel=WebDevSimplified 
            // usar este video para criar uma função que faça append de um novo div com atributos semelhantes aos outros para permitir ao usuario adicionar novos ativos com o cloque de um butao 
            let valuePercentage;

            ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            //Get all the values for each stock input and the quota variation (as "Perda potencial" increases, Quota decreases by a ratio of 1:5 and vice-versa)
            let perda;



            ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            //Load google chart graphs

            google.charts.load("current", { packages: ["corechart"] });
            google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

            //This value percentage is essentially the "Quota". This value will be 100% divided by the amount of slices (essentialy, divided by ativo1, ativo2, ativo3... ativo(i))


            // Function that will add new "Ativo", a new "Quota%" and a new "Perda potencial%". 
            function addStock() {
                for (let i = 6; i <= 15; i++) {
                    let input = document.getElementById(`ativo${i}`).value;
                    input = input.length + 1;
                    document.getElementbyId(`field_div`).innerHTML = document.getElementbyId(`field_div`).innerHTML + `
                    <div class="td" id="field_div"><input type="text" size="5" value="${input}" class="stock" id="ativo${i}"
                            onchange="drawChart();" /> </div>`
                }
            }

            //Function that removes the divs added
            // function removeStock(id) {

            //  for (let i = 6; i <= 10; i++) {
            //      document.getElementById(`ativo${i}`).innerHTML = "";
            //  }
            // }

            //1º Get the lenght, 2º get the IDs
            // let ativoArray;
            // for (let i = 1; i <= 15; i++) { // cap the max amount of ativos at 15
            //  ativoArray = document.getElementById(`ativo${i}`)
            //  //console.log(ativoArray)
            // }

            ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            //Function that will be passed by the "Draw Graph" button so that everytime the user clicks the button, it takes the new input values and updates the pie chart
            function drawChart() {
                const slices = [];
                for (let i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
                    slices.push({
                        ativo: document.getElementById(`ativo${i}`).value,
                        quota: parseFloat(document.getElementById(`quota${i}`).value)
                    })
                }
                valuePercentage = (100 / slices.length);

                //Calculate the Loss (Perda) 
                let sum = 0.0;
                for (let i = 0; i < slices.length; i++) {
                    sum += slices[i].quota;
                };
                perda = 100.0 - sum;

                //Create data table with input data
                var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
                data.addColumn("string", "Ativo");
                data.addColumn("number", "Quota");
                data.addRows([
                    ...slices.map(slice => ([slice.ativo, slice.quota])),
                    ["Perda", perda],
                ]);

                //Styling
                let options = {
                    'legend': 'right',
                    pieHole: 0.3,
                    pieSliceText: 'value',
                    is3D: true,
                    colors: ['#FBB117', '#6AA121', '#728FCE', '#4863A0', '#7D0552', '#FF0000'],
                    backgroundColor: '#DFCFBE',
                    chartArea: {
                        left: 50,
                        right: 50,
                        top: 70
                    }
                };

                var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(
                    document.getElementById("piechart")
                );

                chart.draw(data, options);

            }
            document.querySelector(".row").addEventListener("input", function (e) {
                const tgt = e.target;
                if (tgt.classList.contains("perda")) {
                    perda = Number(tgt.closest(".tr").querySelector(".quota").value =
                        valuePercentage - tgt.value * 0.2) //O 20 será alterado para a expressao de numero de quotas a dividir por 100%

                    //console.log(perda)
                    // quota * perda potencial; var = quota * +- perda potencial / 100
                    //quota - var;
                    //let var = perda/risco potencial
                    //console.log(20 - perda);

                    //isto teria que atualizar sempre que a perda potencial % aumenta ou diminui. Neste momento, apenas faz a soma, nao retira o valor quando perda potencial % diminui e a quota aumenta
                }
            });
            ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

```css
{
        box-sizing: content-box;
    }

    /* Set additional styling options for the columns */
    .column {
        float: left;
    }

    /* Set width length for the left, right and middle columns */
    .left {
        width: 30%;
    }

    .right {
        width: 80%;
    }

    .row:after {
        content: "";
        display: table;
        clear: both;
        height: 100%;
    }

    .td {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 120px;
        text-align: center;
        font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
    }

    .tr {
        font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
    }

    .button1 {

        width: 20%;
        margin-left: 35%;
        margin-right: 25%;
        margin-top: 10px;
        font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;

    }

    .button2 {

        width: 20%;
        margin-left: 35%;
        margin-right: 25%;
        margin-top: 10px;
        font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;

    }

    .piechart {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

</head>

<body style="background-color:#DFCFBE">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="column left">
            <form id=" form">

                <div class="tr">
                    <div class="td">Ativo </div>
                    <div class="td">Quota % </div>
                    <div class="td">Perda Potencial % </div>
                </div>
                <div class="tr" id="wrapper">
                    <div class="td" id="field_div"><input type="text" size="5" value="TSLA" class="stock" id="ativo1"
                            onchange="drawChart();" /> </div>
                    <div class="td"><input type="number" min="0" max="20" value="20" class="quota" id="quota1"
                            onchange="drawChart();" /> </div>
                    <div class="td"><input type="number" min="0" max="100" value="0" class="perda" id="perda1" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="tr" id="wrapper">
                    <div class="td" id="field_div"><input type="text" size="5" value="AAPL" class="stock" id="ativo2"
                            onchange="drawChart();" /> </div>
                    <div class="td"><input type="number" min="0" max="20" value="20" class="quota" id="quota2"
                            onchange="drawChart();" /> </div>
                    <div class="td"><input type="number" min="0" max="100" value="0" class="perda" id="perda2" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="tr" id="wrapper">
                    <div class="td" id="field_div"><input type="text" size="5" value="MSFT" class="stock" id="ativo3"
                            onchange="drawChart();" /> </div>
                    <div class="td"><input type="number" min="0" max="20" value="20" class="quota" id="quota3"
                            onchange="drawChart();" /> </div>
                    <div class="td"><input type="number" min="0" max="100" value="0" class="perda" id="perda3" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="tr" id="wrapper">
                    <div class="td" id="field_div"><input type="text" size="5" value="EURUSD" class="stock"
                            id="ativo4" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="td"><input type="number" min="0" max="20" value="20" class="quota" id="quota4" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="td"><input type="number" min="0" max="100" value="0" class="perda" id="perda4" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="tr" id="wrapper">
                    <div class="td" id="field_div"><input type="text" size="5" value="BITCOIN" class="stock" id="ativo5"
                            onchange="drawChart();" /> </div>
                    <div class="td"><input type="number" min="0" max="20" value="20" class="quota" id="quota5"
                            onchange="drawChart();" /> </div>
                    <div class="td"><input type="number" min="0" max="100" value="0" class="perda" id="perda5" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <button class="button2" type="button" onclick="addStock();">Add Stock</button>
                <button class="button1" type="button" onclick="drawChart();">Draw Graph</button>


            </form>
        </div>

        <div class="column right" style="position:relative;width:70%">
            <div class=" piechart" id="piechart" style="position:absolute;right:0px;top:0px;width: 900; height: 590px;">
            </div>

        </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I see now, let me post a reply for you

Comment: I appreciate your help! :)

Comment: I'm looking in your code, but you have so many multiple id's ..

Comment: I was trying to create a "wrapper" id to possibly add the rest of the children divs and that way add all 3  points (ativos, quota and perda potencial) (same for field_div), but those were added after, they can be removed for sure

The IDs that really matter are "ativo", "quota" and "perda" (and the respective index from 1 to 15 for example)

Comment: I'm also trying to create a removeButton and simply put  10-15 input fields fixed and then the user can just remove them accordingly (Having more than 15 input fields will just cluster the pie chart too much)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, first of all like i did mentioned in the comments, you use multiple identifiers attributes, this is not html5 valid. Identifier attributes need to be unique, about performance etc.., not reason why you post.

I did change you html and used data attributes, we create a Wrapper that we define with `data-type="wrapper"`. We stored the index inside of the html by using another data attribute `data-index="1"`. beware data attributes are slower then storing your data in javascript, but for this small script you will not have any gain by doing so.

We use some dom traversal to get the right elements we want. Also i did change your html with the button `onclick="addStock(event);"` this was because i like to use the `event.currentTarget` and `event.target` properties to have more control about my code instead of using `this`.

In the example below you can have an idea how to future improve your code. deleting like you said you were trying is now kinda easy.

If you have more questions, feel free to comment.

Code;

```
function addStock(event) {

  // find the last Wrapper [data-set="wrapper"]
  let lastWrapper = event.currentTarget.form.querySelector(`[data-type="wrapper"]:last-of-type`);
  // get the index of the last Wrapper
  let lastIndex = lastWrapper.dataset.index;
  
  //not more then 15
  if ( lastIndex < 15 ) {
  
      //clone the wrapper
      let clonerNode = lastWrapper.cloneNode(true);
  
      //change index of cloner Wrapper
      clonerNode.dataset.index = parseInt(lastIndex, 10) + 1;
  
      //changes values;
      clonerNode.querySelector(`.stock`).value = "NEW STOCK";
      clonerNode.querySelector(`.quota`).value = 0;
  
      //append clonernode after lastWrapper
      lastWrapper.insertAdjacentElement('afterend', clonerNode);      
}
```

```js
//https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y17RuWkWdn8&ab_channel=WebDevSimplified 
// usar este video para criar uma função que faça append de um novo div com atributos semelhantes aos outros para permitir ao usuario adicionar novos ativos com o cloque de um butao 
let valuePercentage;

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//Get all the values for each stock input and the quota variation (as "Perda potencial" increases, Quota decreases by a ratio of 1:5 and vice-versa)
let perda;



////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//Load google chart graphs

google.charts.load("current", {
  packages: ["corechart"]
});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

//This value percentage is essentially the "Quota". This value will be 100% divided by the amount of slices (essentialy, divided by ativo1, ativo2, ativo3... ativo(i))


// Function that will add new "Ativo", a new "Quota%" and a new "Perda potencial%". 
function addStock(event) {

  // find the last Wrapper [data-set="wrapper"]
  let lastWrapper = event.currentTarget.form.querySelector(`[data-type="wrapper"]:last-of-type`);
  // get the index of the last Wrapper
  let lastIndex = lastWrapper.dataset.index;
  
  //not more then 15
  if ( lastIndex < 15 ) {
  
  //clone the wrapper
  let clonerNode = lastWrapper.cloneNode(true);
  
  //change index of cloner Wrapper
  clonerNode.dataset.index = parseInt(lastIndex, 10) + 1;
  
  //changes values;
  clonerNode.querySelector(`.stock`).value = "NEW STOCK";
  clonerNode.querySelector(`.quota`).value = 0;
  
  //append clonernode after lastWrapper
  lastWrapper.insertAdjacentElement('afterend', clonerNode);
  
  
  
  
   }

  console.log(lastIndex);

}

//Function that removes the divs added
// function removeStock(id) {

//  for (let i = 6; i <= 10; i++) {
//      document.getElementById(`ativo${i}`).innerHTML = "";
//  }
// }

//1º Get the lenght, 2º get the IDs
// let ativoArray;
// for (let i = 1; i <= 15; i++) { // cap the max amount of ativos at 15
//  ativoArray = document.getElementById(`ativo${i}`)
//  //console.log(ativoArray)
// }

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//Function that will be passed by the "Draw Graph" button so that everytime the user clicks the button, it takes the new input values and updates the pie chart
function drawChart() {
  const slices = [];
  for (let i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
//    slices.push({
//      ativo: document.getElementById(`ativo${i}`).value,
//      quota: parseFloat(document.getElementById(`quota${i}`).value)
//    })
  slices.push({
     ativo: document.querySelector(`div [data-type="wrapper"][data-index="${i}"] .stock`).value,
     quota: parseFloat(document.querySelector(`div [data-type="wrapper"][data-index="${i}"] .quota`).value)
   })


  }
  valuePercentage = (100 / slices.length);

  //Calculate the Loss (Perda) 
  let sum = 0.0;
  for (let i = 0; i < slices.length; i++) {
    sum += slices[i].quota;
  };
  perda = 100.0 - sum;

  //Create data table with input data
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn("string", "Ativo");
  data.addColumn("number", "Quota");
  data.addRows([
    ...slices.map(slice => ([slice.ativo, slice.quota])), ["Perda", perda],
  ]);

  //Styling
  let options = {
    'legend': 'right',
    pieHole: 0.3,
    pieSliceText: 'value',
    is3D: true,
    colors: ['#FBB117', '#6AA121', '#728FCE', '#4863A0', '#7D0552', '#FF0000'],
    backgroundColor: '#DFCFBE',
    chartArea: {
      left: 50,
      right: 50,
      top: 70
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(
    document.getElementById("piechart")
  );

  chart.draw(data, options);

}
document.querySelector(".row").addEventListener("input", function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.classList.contains("perda")) {
    perda = Number(tgt.closest(".tr").querySelector(".quota").value =
      valuePercentage - tgt.value * 0.2) //O 20 será alterado para a expressao de numero de quotas a dividir por 100%

    //console.log(perda)
    // quota * perda potencial; var = quota * +- perda potencial / 100
    //quota - var;
    //let var = perda/risco potencial
    //console.log(20 - perda);

    //isto teria que atualizar sempre que a perda potencial % aumenta ou diminui. Neste momento, apenas faz a soma, nao retira o valor quando perda potencial % diminui e a quota aumenta
  }
});
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

```css
{
  box-sizing: content-box;
}


/* Set additional styling options for the columns */

.column {
  float: left;
}


/* Set width length for the left, right and middle columns */

.left {
  width: 30%;
}

.right {
  width: 80%;
}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
  height: 100%;
}

.td {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 120px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
}

.tr {
  font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
}

.button1 {
  width: 20%;
  margin-left: 35%;
  margin-right: 25%;
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
}

.button2 {
  width: 20%;
  margin-left: 35%;
  margin-right: 25%;
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
}

.piechart {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<body style="background-color:#DFCFBE">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="column left">
      <form id=" form">

        <div class="tr">
          <div class="td">Ativo </div>
          <div class="td">Quota % </div>
          <div class="td">Perda Potencial % </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tr" data-type="wrapper" data-index="1">
          <div class="td" data-type="field_div"><input type="text" size="5" value="TSLA" class="stock" onchange="drawChart();" /> </div>
          <div class="td"><input type="number" min="0" max="20" value="20" class="quota" onchange="drawChart();" /> </div>
          <div class="td"><input type="number" min="0" max="100" value="0" class="perda" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tr" data-type="wrapper" data-index="2">
          <div class="td" data-type="field_div"><input type="text" size="5" value="AAPL" class="stock" onchange="drawChart();" /> </div>
          <div class="td"><input type="number" min="0" max="20" value="20" class="quota" onchange="drawChart();" /> </div>
          <div class="td"><input type="number" min="0" max="100" value="0" class="perda" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tr" data-type="wrapper" data-index="3">
          <div class="td" data-type="field_div"><input type="text" size="5" value="MSFT" class="stock" onchange="drawChart();" /> </div>
          <div class="td"><input type="number" min="0" max="20" value="20" class="quota" onchange="drawChart();" /> </div>
          <div class="td"><input type="number" min="0" max="100" value="0" class="perda" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tr" data-type="wrapper" data-index="4">
          <div class="td" data-type="field_div"><input type="text" size="5" value="EURUSD" class="stock" />
          </div>
          <div class="td"><input type="number" min="0" max="20" value="20" class="quota" />
          </div>
          <div class="td"><input type="number" min="0" max="100" value="0" class="perda" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tr" data-type="wrapper" data-index="5">
          <div class="td" data-type="field_div"><input type="text" size="5" value="BITCOIN" class="stock" onchange="drawChart();" /> </div>
          <div class="td"><input type="number" min="0" max="20" value="20" class="quota" onchange="drawChart();" /> </div>
          <div class="td"><input type="number" min="0" max="100" value="0" class="perda" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <button class="button2" type="button" onclick="addStock(event);">Add Stock</button>
        <button class="button1" type="button" onclick="drawChart();">Draw Graph</button>


      </form>
    </div>

    <div class="column right" style="position:relative;width:70%">
      <div class=" piechart" id="piechart" style="position:absolute;right:0px;top:0px;width: 900; height: 590px;">
      </div>

    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I really appreciate your help brother! :)

Comment: De nada Señor, we need to help each other :)